# MySQL trigger on warning

Tags: mysql, triggers, warnings

I'm using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to upload a file to a MySQL table.
Since this file is created by users it can contain a lot of Inconsistent data and wrong formatted.
Currently I'm catching those warning with the following code:

```
if (mysqli_warning_count($conn)) { 
  $e = mysqli_get_warnings($conn); 
  do { 
    $conn->query("CALL import_warning($id, '$e->errno', '$e->message');"; 
  } while ($e->next()); 
}
```

Is there anyway of doing this in MySQL, like a trigger on a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and no.

`mysqli_get_warnings()` function produces the same output as [show warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-warnings.html) MySQL statement. So, there is a way to get the list of warnings from pure sql code. However, the `show` statement is handled differently by MySQL than a simple `select`.

Unfortunately, this means that you cannot properly process the resultset of any `show` statement in a stored procedure, therefore you cannot properly log the warnings after the import.

Comment: So the best thing to do use PHP to log the warnings, right?

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do.